# How I can revert my method of checking reaching the bottom of list for checking reaching the top (recyclerView)?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my application I have to check whether user reached the bottom or top of list at recyclerView. I have created special interface:

```
public interface OnBottomReachedListener {
    void onBottomReached(int position);
}
```

and then I insert one method to adapter:

```
void setOnBottomReachedListener(OnBottomReachedListener onBottomReachedListener) {
        this.onBottomReachedListener = onBottomReachedListener;
    }
```

inserted these lines to `onBindViewHolder`:

```
if (position ==getItemCount() - 1) {
            onBottomReachedListener.onBottomReached(position);
        }
```

and in general it works fine, but I don't understand how I can use the following method for checking reaching the top of list. Maybe someone has some ideas which will help me?

### edit

I tried smth like this at my adapter:

```
if (position == 0) {
            //onTopReachedListener.onTopReached(position);
            Log.w("MY_TAG", String.valueOf(position));
        }
```

but it throws me an exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.developer_4.test_login.MessageCenter.OnTopReachedListener.onTopReached(int)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Check item position with 0 and also check for your adapter has some data so it doesn't return false positive.

Comment: @Amit, I have to check item position at the adapter? or at the activity?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko you can check that in the adapter

Comment: @SaurabhMishra, I understood it, if you check my edition, you will see that I get an error while I check the position. But at the logcat I can see my position as 0.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko the exception you are getting is most likely because you are calling onTopReached on an interface reference, so my advice is to call it after you set the listener first

Comment: @SaurabhMishra, in general, I managed to do something that looks like what I want, BUT, the listener works all the time, and sometimes I don’t need it. My listener usually works when I reach the top, but for example I don’t need it, and I can’t do anything about it